# printing stdout to console - unix

Tags: unix, logging, stdout, stderr

How do i send stdout to console and stderr to a file?  So far the closest I've come is:

eval $JOB_EXEC_CMD >> $LOG_FILE 1>&2

but this writing both the logs and output to console.   I just want stdout to console and everything else to file

Thanks in advance

Comment: `>>` redirects stdout, but then you do `1>&2` which redirects stdout (1) to stderr (2) so ALL of your output is stderr now.

Answer (score 1):

```
eval $JOB_EXEC_CMD 2>> $LOG_FILE
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: No, got busy with something, was gonna troubleshoot it a little more to see if your solution works, but I have a configuration conflicting somewhere else.  I'll update you as soon as I've had a chance to play with it more.   Thanks!